# Solvability of inhomogeneous linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In applied mechanics the following equation is common.
$$w^{(4)}+k^2 w''=f$$ defined on (0,1),subject to homogeneous boundary conditions:
$$w(0)=w''(0)=w(1)=w''(1)=0$$. It seems that if $ k$ is an eigen value such that the homogeneous version of the above equation $w^{(4)}+k^2 w''=0$ has an eigenfunction $w^*$, then it seems necessary that:
$$\int_0^1 f w^*=0 $$ to ensure there is a solution to the original inhomogeneous equation. Although this fact is used commonly in applied mechanics analysis, I don't see the way to prove it. Could any one give a proof of it.

Comment: Multiply the equation by $w^*$, integrate, and apply integrate by parts until all derivatives are moved onto $w^*$.  The homogeneous BCs ensure the boundary terms vanish, and the definition of $w^*$ cancels the remaining integral.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I have a further question if $\int_0^1 fw^*=0$ is satisfied then what is the expression of solution $w$?

Comment: Does $w^*$ refer to the conjugate?

Comment: @Dylan, what do u mean by conjugate? $w^*$ is the eigenfunction of homogenous equation as stated in this question.

Comment: Ok I missed that somehow. $w^*$ is a common notation for the complex conjugate. So $w^*$ here is just a solution to the homogeneous equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the integral
$$\begin{align} 
&\quad \int_0^1 w^{(4)}w^* + k^2 \int_0^1 w''w^* \\
&= w'''w^*\Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1 w'''{w^*}' + k^2w'w^*\Big|_0^1 - k^2\int_0^1w'{w^*}' \\
&= w'''w^*\Big|_0^1 + \int_0^1 w''{w^*}'' + k^2w'w^*\Big|_0^1 + k^2\int_0^1w{w^*}'' \\
&= w'''w^*\Big|_0^1 + w'{w^*}''\Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1 w' {w^*}''' + k^2w'w^*\Big|_0^1 + k^2\int_0^1w{w^*}'' \\
&= w'''w^*\Big|_0^1 + w'{w^*}''\Big|_0^1 + \int_0^1 w {w^*}^{(4)} + k^2w'w^*\Big|_0^1 + k^2\int_0^1w{w^*}'' \\
&= w'''w^*\Big|_0^1 + w'({w^*}'' + k^2w^*)\Big|_0^1 
\end{align} $$

without any information on the odd derivatives, this can't be simplified further

---

For the equation, you can use Green's function to solve it. If $u(x,s)$ satisfies

$$ u^{(4)}(x,s) + k^2u''(x,s) = \delta(x-s) $$

Then $$ w(x) = \int_0^1 u(x,s)f(s)\ ds $$

Let's solve for $u$. For $x \ne s$ the general solution is
$$ u(x,s) =c_0 + c_1x + c_2\cos(kx) + c_3\sin(kx) = 0 $$
where $c_i$ are dependent on $s$

Using the B.C. at $x=0$ for $x<s$ and at $x=1$ for $x > s$ we obtain the piecewise solution
$$ u(s,x) = \begin{cases} a_1x + a_2\sin (kx), && x < s \\
b_1(1-x) + b_2\sin\big(k(1-x)\big), && x > s \end{cases} $$

For continuity, we require
$$ \begin{align} 
u(s,s) &= a_1s + a_2\sin(ks) = b_1(1-s) + b_2\sin((k(1-s)) \\ \\ 
u'(s,s) &= a_1 + ka_2\cos(ks) = -b_1s - kb_2\cos(k(1-s)) \\ \\
u''(s,s) &= -k^2a_2\sin(ks) = -k^2b_2\sin(k(1-s))
\end{align}$$

We also need discontinuity in the third derivative (which you can check by integrating the original equation throughout)
$$ u'''(s^+,s) - u'''(s^-,s) = k^3a_2\cos(ks) + k^3b_2\cos(k(1-s)) = 1 $$

Solving the above system gives
$$ \begin{array}{ll} 
a_1 = \dfrac{1-s}{k^2(1-s+s^2)}, && b_1 = \dfrac{s}{k^2(1-s+s^2)} \\ 
a_2 = \dfrac{\sin(k(1-s))}{k^3\sin k}, && b_2 = \dfrac{\sin(ks)}{k^3\sin k}
\end{array} $$

---

Note that if $k=0$, the solution takes a different form
$$ u(x,s) = \begin{cases} a_1x^3 + a_2x, && x < s \\ 
b_1(1-x)^3 + b_2(1-x), && x > s \end{cases} $$

with the same conditions as before

$$ \begin{array}{ll}
a_1 = -\dfrac{1-s}{6}, && b_1 = -\dfrac{s}{6} \\ 
a_2 = \dfrac{s(1-s)(2-s)}{6}, && b_2 = \dfrac{s(1-s)(1+s)}{6} 
\end{array} $$